# Getting [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input

Tags: react-native, podfile

Can someone please help? It seems to not be accepting my podfile even though I think I have the correct syntax. I'm getting [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'
use_frameworks!

target: 'Neat' do
  
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'Permission-BluetoothPeripheral', :path => "#{permissions_path}/BluetoothPeripheral.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Calendars', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Calendars.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Contacts', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Contacts.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-FaceID', :path => "#{permissions_path}/FaceID.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Microphone', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Microphone.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Motion', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Motion.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Reminders', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Reminders.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Siri', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Siri.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-SpeechRecognition', :path => "#{permissions_path}/SpeechRecognition.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-StoreKit', :path => "#{permissions_path}/StoreKit.podspec"
  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  pod 'react-native-geolocation', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'
  pod 'ReactNativeGetLocation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-get-location'
  pod 'amplify-tools'
  pod 'Amplify'
  pod 'AWSPluginsCore'
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSAPIPlugin'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end

  target: 'NeatTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target: 'NeatUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing : after the two targets at the end. it should be

`target 'NeatTests' do`
and

`target 'NeatUITests' do`

also,
`target 'Neat' do`